# Compare a non-static data member with a constant member

Tags: c++, c++11

Following is the code, where I wanted to compare a non-static data member `check` with a constant data member `NULL_NODE` defined in the class.

Why is it not able to compare? 
what would be a recommended approach to have the `is_null` functionality as described in the code and keeping `NULL_NODE` a non-modifiable entity?

```
class test {
public:
    struct st {
        int check;
        bool is_null() const { return NULL_NODE == check; }
    };

private:
    const int NULL_NODE{-1};

};


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Code was compiled with following command:
`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`

Exception reported:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘bool test::st::is_null() const’:
test.cpp:8:39: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘test::NULL_NODE’
         bool is_null() const { return NULL_NODE == check; }
                                       ^
test.cpp:12:27: note: declared here
     const int NULL_NODE{-1};
```

Comment: `check` and `NULL_NODE` are not members of the same class, you can't just use them.

Comment: What is your question? Why the error happens? How to fix? Anything else? You can [edit] your post to specify the question.

Comment: @DeiDei Inner classes are implicitly friends of the outer class, so it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to reference to `non-static` variable inside your `struct st`? It is not possible, as you will never know which instance of `test` should be referenced to.

In other words, the inner struct has no reference to surrounding class - to compare, in Java inner classes do have that reference, unless the inner class is declared `static`.

Notice how the following code compiles:

```
int main() {
    test::st x; /* instance of your struct, without any reference to "test" class" */
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, you need to declare your `NULL_NODE` as `static const`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL_NODE is const but it's not static, that is every 'test' instance will have its own copy and hence an 'st' instance cannot know which one to refer to; the solution is to make it static.

In pre-c++17 you should also define it in some translation unit (unless non ODR-used) (or resort to a static inline member function); from c++17 on we have inline variables, so you just define it as 'static constexpr' ( constexpr members are automatically inline and const ).